Safety per bit DHKA and ECDH
I have a project where I compare the classical Diffie Hellman key agreement with its implementation with elliptic curves. Therefore I need a list with the safety per bit. Does anyone know where I can find such a list?

keylength.com for classical adversaries, for quantum adversaries it is a different strory
